# importing graph into geopandas using networkx

Tags: networkx, geopandas

Is it possible to create a node edge graph in geopandas or can we in anyway import networkx graph into geopandas. I want to create a directed graph in geopandas.

Comment: have you looked into **osmnx** ?  do you have any sample code / data?